# Everything works but the subject line blank... why? What am I missing?

Tags: google-apps-script

I think this must be very easy to see, but I cannot see it! This script sends out a sheet as a PDF. It works well, except that the subject line is blank. I've tried substituting an actual string for the variable in the class gmailApp at the bottom, but the subject line is still blank when the email arrives. Help! Thank you.
P.S.-- note that I took out the email address for privacy.

```
function emailPDF(email, subject, body, sheetName) {

    var email = "...";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Client');
    var cost = sheet.getSheetValues(1,1,1,1).toLocaleString();
    var subject = ss.getName();
    var body = "Hi Serenity, the material cost is $" + cost +" Thank you!";

    // Base URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

    /* Specify PDF export parameters
    From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
     */

    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
         + '&size=letter' // paper size legal / letter / A4
         + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
         + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
         + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
         + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
         + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
         + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        }).getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");

    // save PDF to drive 
    //  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf")

  
    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
            htmlBody : body,
            attachments : [response]
        });
}
```

Comment: So you provide a `subject` using [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options), and the sent email does not have a subject? I cannot reproduce this. Make sure you are not missing anything (are you looking at the correct email? Are you sure `subject` is not an empty string? etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out... this was just petty error. The spreadsheet has a lot of scripts. I picked up this script from a month ago, started from scratch and accidentally gave it the same function name. Both scripts were being called simultaneously, causing this result. Everything works now.
I appreciate your comment Lamblichus... I was so focused on the script being wrong that I didn't realize what was happening. Then I realized that it can't be wrong. You got me thinking the right way. Best.